# How to prove a set is closed

Tags: probability, general-topology, compactness

Let $\left(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P}\right)$ be a finite probability space equipped with a filtration, i.e an increasing sequence of $\sigma$-algebras included in $\mathcal{F}$ : $\mathcal{F}_0, \mathcal{F}_1, \ldots, \mathcal{F}_N$. Denote $\Gamma$ the set of all non-negative random variables X such that $\mathbb{P}$ (X > 0) > 0. Let K = $\{X \in \Gamma \mid \sum_{w} X\left(w\right) = 1\}$. Show that K is a convex compact set.

I know how to show that K is a convex set, and since I'm dealing with a finite probability space, so if I want to show that K is a compact set, I just need to show that K is a bounded and closed set. The problem is that I don't know how to show that K is a closed set. Can anyone help me to proof that?

Thank you.

Comment: I'm not an expert on probability, but isn't a finite set in a topological space always compact? After all, every open covering can be reduced to a finite one (at most one open set per point)

Comment: Probably the easiest way is to define a continuous function from $\Gamma$ to $\mathbb{R}$ such that your set $K$ is the pre-image of $\{ 1 \}$.

Comment: @RiccardoOrlando There is not an ounce of probability in the question (which is why I added some more relevant tags).

Comment: @Did But... but it is a probability space!

Comment: @RiccardoOrlando Exercise: Rewrite the question with the idea of keeping only what is needed to ask it. You should soon realize that the first sentence of the current version disappears.